# Can Microsoft Cognitive APIs be used in local cloud

Tags: cloud, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on running few examples on Microsoft Face API, I would like to know if there is a possibility that i can send the request to my local cloudlet to fetch and retrieve information instead of sending the request to Microsoft?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short answer is not possible.

Current there is no local deployment support. And there is no specific plan to support that too.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the reply